# How to store (small) updates to html efficiently for a custom undo-stack in javascript?

Tags: javascript, undo-redo

I'm building a CMS using `contenteditable` (comparable to [aloha](http://www.aloha-editor.org/about.php) for instance). I'm monkey-patching ctrl+z / ctrl+y (undo/redo) since some commands can't be executed with the native `document.execCommand` and so don't end up in the native undo-stack.

Therefore, I want to implement a space-efficient undo-stack myself. Since the entries in such a stack will only be small differences on the html (most of the time at least) it seems logical to go with some sort of delta/diff encoding for storage.

Is there anything out there (javascript) that would cover this usecase nicely? Alternatively, other/better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Some points to cover in your implementation:

- save points
- storage
- retrieval

For illustration purposes, I'm going to use an Undo button, a Save button, and a Text field.

You *could* use an interval/timer to automatically save the changes each time the text field is changed; or you can rely on the "Save" button to explicitly create save points.

The timer implementation compares the current text with the previous snapshot. If the text is changed AND enough time is passed, a save point is created. You may use the onkeyup event to trigger autosave.

The next point is storage. If the intermittent changes don't have to persist, you may use in-memory storage; or simply JavaScript functions. Attach a "history" object to the DOM element. In this case the textarea object.

```
<button onclick="undo();">Undo</button>
<textarea id="text" onkeyup="autosave()"></textarea>

<script>
function autosave(){
  var text=document.getElementById('text');
  var date=new Date(); var now=date.getTime();
  if (text.lastsaved==null) text.lastsaved=now;
  if (now-text.lastsaved<5000) return; //ignore changes within 5 seconds

  if (text.savetimer) clearTimeout(text.savetimer);
  text.savetimer=setTimeout(function(){
    if (!text.undohist) text.undohist=[];
    text.undohist.push(text.value); //save a snapshot
    text.lastsaved=now;
  }, 300); //if keys are continuously pressed, wait until it "settles down"
}

function undo(){
  var text=document.getElementById('text');
  var date=new Date(); var now=date.getTime();

  if (!text.undohist) return; //cannot undo any more

  if (text.undohist.length==0) return;

  text.value=text.undohist.pop();
  text.lastupdated=now;
}
</script>
```

If you'd like a "Redo" function, create another attribute to hold the last undo value, so that you can undo the undo.

Comment: nicely hacked together this fast :) I was actually more concerned about the space-efficient storage of the stack, but I like your straightforward implementation. Perhaps I shouldn't concern myself with diffing for now and just store the stuff verbatim on each savepoint. Btw; I'd go with savepoints on each mouseclick on a contenteditable (i.e.: saving the changes when a mouseclick occurs, indicating 'done writing' ) which is how the native redo seems to work for contenteditables (in chrome at least). That, and the other special CMS-actions taken on the content.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I'm also curious about the storage usage, not knowing the kind of information you are storing. You could have a max undo limit, or "archive" the really old undos (AND the most recent undo) with persistent storage. That'll probably make the application more scalable and lighter at the same time.